# Text to speech, sentence by sentence

Tags: windows-10, speech-synthesis, accessibility

I want a text to speech functionality.
When I press a certain key, the next sentence is read.
When I press another key, the same sentence will be read again.

I want to manually select language (no autodetection) and swedish must be one of them.

The requirement is not met in Microsoft word as I have tried it this far. You have to select all text before it can be read and it does not pause when a sentence has ben read. It is not sentence aware at all.
It does also auto detect the language.

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: Windows 10, added tag now.

Comment: It seems like web speech api is the one to use, so I have to just code a webpage.

Comment: Hm, no swedish...

Comment: Google Translate does Swedish. Don’t know if it does text to speech, but you might check.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices

Comment: I cannot use that API in a larger extent without paying, I think.

Comment: No idea of costs. You didn’t specify free in your question. If you search you can find some free options, but I have no idea if they are any good.